# Trying to complete a SUM, using index/match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to sum multiple rows and columns in a table, depending on what week and region they are:

Id like to sum all the numbers that all into WK-8, and then based on region, E N S W

The below image is a small sample of the data table

[image]

Comment: mind sharing and formulae you had tried? [ref1](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria) [ref2](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumifs-function)

Comment: I can do the following formula, to get a match on the first number. 

But cant get it to sum

Comment: =INDEX('Lost and Retired Farms'!$E$26:$AT$452,MATCH(Sheet1!$B3,'Lost and Retired Farms'!$A$26:$A$452,0),MATCH(Sheet1!C$1,'Lost and Retired Farms'!$E$18:$AT$18,0))

Comment: have tried using sum ifs, then the above, and i get an error

Comment: At which cell was the formula applied to? And the screenshot is Sheet1 or other sheet?

Comment: screenshot above is 'lost and retired farms'

Sheet 1 is going to be the summary tab, so where i am putting the output of the lookup

Comment: "can do the formula.. But cant get it to sum ".. so the problem is in Sheet1.. not in the 'lost and retired farms' sheet... right?

Comment: any printscreen from there?

Comment: are the regions sorted, or are the mixed up with one another?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works on the assumption that your regions and your weeks are sorted.  This will result in all the same region being in adjacent columns and all the same weeks being in adjacent rows.  Based on this assumption all that needs to be done is define the corners of your range (or selection box if you prefer) and dump that into a sum function.

See image below for range references used and adjust to suit your needs.

In order to do this, the following solution will require the use of the following formulas:

- AGGREGATE
- ROW
- COLUMN
- INDEX
- SUM

AGGREGATE is a whole bunch of different formulas lumped into one function.  It takes the following format:

```
AGGREGATE(formula #, Option#,ARRAY/RANGE, Parameter)
```

The formulas used for this solution are 14 and 15.  These two particular formulas cause AGGREGATE to perform array like calculations within the AGGREGATE function.  As a result of this avoid using full column/row references such as A:A or 2:2 within AGGREGATE or you can wind up with a lot of excess calculation.  Formulas 14 will sort the array from largest to smallest and 15 will sort from smallest to largest.

There are several option # available which can tell AGGREGATE to ignore certain conditions such as hidden info or error values.  For this solution 6 will be used which tells AGGREGATE to ignore all errors.

The array/range part is where a list of row or column numbers that match our criteria will be developed.

The parameter for the formula we are using will tell AGGREGATE which position in the array to return a value from.

Based on the information above, this solution will use AGGREGATE to determine the FIRST and LAST ROW and COLUMN number.  4 distinct formulas will be used, but they will be very similar to one another.

So the basic set up of the formula will be:

```
Last ROW/COL
=AGGREGATE(14,6,ARRAY,1)
or
First ROW/COL
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ARRAY,1)
```

So the hard part will be developing the ARRAY.  Lets start with the column and then follow the same method and get the row.  To get a list of potential column numbers you will need the following formula:

```
COLUMN(D4:G4)
```

That will give you all the column numbers.  Now you need to add your criteria in this case we will use a criteria where the column is equal to something.  This could vary for other scenarios where you might want all columns greater than a certain date, or not equal to a value.  in those cases you would just need to change the comparison operator to suit your needs.  So the key here is when we match something we want, we get a TRUE value, and when something does not match you get a FALSE value.  More importantly, when TRUE and FALSE are acted on by a math operator such as +, -, *, /, ^, etc they will be converted to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.  Sending them through a Function like SUM will not always do the conversion.  So the reason this is important is we want to exclude all the things that do not match what we are looking for.  They will return a value of False.  We will divide the potential column numbers according to their true and false.  Which means we will be dividing by 1 and 0.  If you divide by 0 you will generate an error.  Because we chose 6 in AGGREGATE to ignore errors those column numbers will be excluded from the sorted list and you will be just left with the column numbers you want. So the ARRAY formula portion becomes:

```
COLUMN(D4:G4)/(D4:G4=C14)
```

Now drop that into the AGGREGATE formula and you get:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(D4:G4)/(D4:G4=C14),1)
```

That will get you the first column number.  To get the first row number, we just need to change the array portion to row operations as follows:

```
ROW(C5:C8)/(C5:C8=C13)
```

and then dump that into the AGGREGATE function to get:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(D4:G4)/(D4:G4=C14),1)
```

So using the above two AGGREGATE functions you now have the first column and the first row.  In order to get the last column and last row, the sort order of the array portion just needs to be reversed which can be done by changing AGGREGATE from using formula 15 to using formula 14.  Your corresponding formulas become:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(D4:G4)/(D4:G4=C14),1)
=AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(D4:G4)/(D4:G4=C14),1)
```

So now you have the location of the top left and bottom right of the area you want to sum.  You could go through some other methods to define your range like using OFFSET, but that is a volatile function.  Volatile functions will cause the sheet to recalculate anytime anything in the worksheet/workbook changes.  This can lead to a lot of unnecessary calculation.  Instead INDEX will be used which is a regular function.  It only recalculates when something that affects it changes.

Most people make the assumption that the result of index is the value of cell it returns.  In reality index returns a cell address.  this cell address in turn fetches the value in that cell.  This means you can actually write a range address with two index functions as follows:

```
INDEX(...):INDEX(...)
```

Now you just need to get INDEX to look through all the columns and rows in the sheet and define the column and row your are interested in.  Which AGGREGATE has determine for us.  so the INDEX formula for the top left cell is:

```
=INDEX(1:1048576,C18,C16)
```

and the INDEX for the bottom right cell is:

```
=INDEX(1:1048576,C19,C17)
```

If you enter those as formulas what you will see is not the address as previously discussed but the value at that address.  Potentially a good way to verify it is picking the right values though

To define the range you will want to take the sum of, take the above formulas and place a : between them as follows:

```
INDEX(1:1048576,C18,C16):INDEX(1:1048576,C19,C17)
```

The above wont really work in a cell on its own, but since it is the range you want the sum of, you can drop the above range into a SUM function resulting in the following formula:

```
SUM(INDEX(1:1048576,C18,C16):INDEX(1:1048576,C19,C17))
```

So by breaking the formula down into parts where possible, the formula is short and relatively easy to read, and therefore easier to maintain.  IF you really need to have it all in one cell, you can substitute the individual formulas into one another to get the following long, ugly, hard to read formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(1:1048576,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C5:C8)/(C5:C8=C11),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(D4:G4)/(D4:G4=C12),1)):INDEX(1:1048576,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(C5:C8)/(C5:C8=C11),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(D4:G4)/(D4:G4=C12),1)))
```

[image: POC]